# Excel formula for calculating work percentages / month for each employee according to work periods

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have just struggled to teach Excel how to calculate the monthly employment rate for each employee. I have the following input data:

- One entry per employee for each period of employment, along with the corresponding workload. For example:

  Max Mustermann,01.01.2023,31.12.2023,100%

However, it is possible that an employee has been employed for less than a full month, with different workloads for each period. For example:

```
Xi Jingping,10.07.2023,23.07.2023,40%
Xi Jingping,24.07.2023,27.08.2023,100%
```

Now, I would like to create an Excel table as the output that reflects the average employment rate for each employee per month:

```
Max Mustermann,Jan,31.00,100.00%
```

In the second-to-last column, the number of days worked at 100% equivalent should be entered. However, the formula poses a little problem because I need to extract all the entries from the above table and accumulate the employment time that applies to each respective month (*since there can be multiple employment periods within a month!*).

With some tinkering, I have created the following formula:

```
=LET(nameFiltered;FILTER(EmployeeData[[Start]:[Workload]];EmployeeData[Name]=[@Employee]);LET(row;INDEX(nameFiltered;1;0);MAX(MIN(INDEX(row;0;2);EOMONTH([@Month];0))-MAX(INDEX(row;0;1);[@Month])+1;0)*INDEX(row;0;3)))
```

It's best to check the original table (attached).

The problem with this formula is that it only retrieves the first entry for each specific user and does the calculation with that. However, I need to repeat the formula

```
MAX(MIN(INDEX(row;0;2);EOMONTH([@Month];0))-MAX(INDEX(row;0;1);[@Month])+1;0)*INDEX(row;0;3))
```

for each row and then sum the results. How can I do that?

Link to my file: [Excel table](https://file.io/d7VHE2i7wDzJ)

Comment: Please use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to paste some sample data and the result you expect from it.

Comment: Rather than trying to do it all in one formula, break down the logic to what you can explain to yourself, and build formulae to do each stage. You don't have to pay anybody for using more space in a workbook, so use the space generously!